# Enabling Beaker SessionMiddleware through Bottle on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi, bottle, beaker

I am trying to use beaker for session handling in my bottle based GAE app. The problem is that I need to run "app" here as the app

```
session_opts = {
    'session.type': 'ext:google',
    'session.auto': True,
}

app = beaker.middleware.SessionMiddleware(bottle.app(), session_opts)
```

then call

```
bottle.run(app=app)
```

but I can't because as it says in the example bottle app:

```
# Note: We don't need to call run() since our application is embedded within
# the App Engine WSGI application server.
```

So my question is how can I run the server with the beaker session middleware?

Comment: `app = beaker.middl..` isn't enough? it needs to be run?

Comment: @GianniDiNoia Yeah I'm pretty sure that would just assign app with the object that I want to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have found the cause of the problem - thanks for getting me to think Gianni. Basically I had

```
- url: .*
  script: main.bottle
```

which means that GAE treats the bottle variable in my main.py as the "app". So when I did this instead:

```
from bottle import app, route, hook...

session_opts = {
    'session.type': 'ext:google',
    'session.auto': True,
}

bottle = beaker.middleware.SessionMiddleware(app(), session_opts)
```

It all worked a treat. Guess that'll teach me for not reading the app engine docs enough.